# How can protobuf-net serialization/deserialization produce collection items duplicates?

Tags: .net, serialization, protobuf-net

We have SortedSet collection that doesn't allow duplicates. We serialize/deserialize it with protobuf-net. All works, but sometimes very-very seldom ‎ with unknow reasons deserialization fails because
collection will contain duplicate after deserialization. Do you have any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: I would check what the serialized data contains. The wire format for protocol buffers isn't *easy* to understand, but it's far from impossible too :)

Comment: @Brans what type of data is the value in the sorted set? Is it possible this is two really close values that are colliding due to rounding?